# How can I have a floating image (right aligned) with text that wraps around the image in Android Layout?

Tags: android, image, layout, floating

It's kind of hard to explain, but an example of what I'm wanting to accomplish is like this:

```
Here is some text | image |
that is printed   |       |
out in a view and ---------
it is wrapped around an
image that is floating and
right aligned.
```

I thought about generating the layout in html and using a web view, but I need to be able to perform an action when the user clicks on the image. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

groomsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you must work with some html code, creating a template for your webview...

```
     String TemplateHTML =

"<div id=\"content\">[Replace with your CONTENT]</div><div id=\"myimage\"><a id=\"mylink\" onClick=\"window.demo.clickOnAndroid()\"><img id=\"myImage\" src=\"[Replace your image URL path]\" /></a></div>"
```

Create  JSInterface to interact with your template

```
    final class myJavaScriptInterface {
        myJavaScriptInterface () {
        }
        public void clickOnAndroid() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
Log.i("myJavaScriptInterface " ,"Jorge is Clickin the image!!! =D");        
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

add the interface and your Template  to your webview!

```
MyWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface (), "demo");     
    MyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, TemplateHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    WebSettings webSettings = WebContent.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. That made a lot of sense. I was trying to find a way of doing it with TextViews and ImageViews, but this example works well for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it without html ...
https://github.com/goingkilo/flowing-text-for-android-/blob/master/screenshot3.png

Comment: -1, could you provide a snippet of code that produces that image?

Comment: The complete source code is available on github, what more do you want?