# ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

My ListView has to be customized like, it should have three imageView in each ListItem along with the name and date that has to populated from the DB,added with that, once i click upon the a list item ,that corresponding Listitem information has to be displayed in another Screen...The Size of the List should be based on the Cursor object from DB..and it should be possible to add data in to the Listview..too

Can anybody give me any suggestion/snippet/resource of how to proceed the above said..

Please check the ScreenShot of ListView that i mentioned..(My ListView should have to be like this only)..

[image: SampleListView]

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: or.. is that same functionality can be implemented using TableLayout ? if so please provide some resource,... i am confused... Any help Appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

you can use inside every list item a WebView loadin your html template that contains the name, date and the 3 images, and use a JavaScript interface to interact with your code

you must load in every listitem something similar to this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991718/how-can-i-have-a-floating-image-right-aligned-with-text-that-wraps-around-the-i/2992124#2992124) but with 3 images.

hope it helps you