# How to align image to top right corner of textView?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to display a long text, which alings its right to the left of image, but when it goes beyond the height of image, it should align its right to parent.

I tried something like this, but its not working:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/next" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
    android:text="Text...." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991718/how-can-i-have-a-floating-image-right-aligned-with-text-that-wraps-around-the

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12971408/3020568

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how you could achieve this. (e.g. using a [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)) Unfortunately none is really easy. The easiest solution would be to use a library called `FlowTextView` ([Click](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)).

> A TextView that extends RelativeLayout. The text will wrap around any child views inside the layout.
>
> This widget has basic support for HTML using Html.fromHtml("< your markup ... />") It will recognise links, bold italic etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/next"
        android:text="Text...." />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use TextView's drawableRight